# Regex - getting rid of extra tags based on certain conditions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using a third party tool that generates HTML as follows [this is just a sample html with a long page but the pattern is the same]:

```
<P>
    <SPAN>
        <SPAN>This is </SPAN>
    </SPAN>
    <SPAN STYLE="font-weight:bold;">
        <SPAN>some</SPAN>
    </SPAN>
    <SPAN>
        <SPAN> text.</SPAN>
    </SPAN>
</P>
```

I want it to be more **cleaner** as follows [indentation does not matter]:

```
<P>
    This is <SPAN STYLE="font-weight:bold;">some</SPAN> text.
</P>
```

Following `Regex` gives me text between tags. For example, `[span]some sample text[/span]` gives me `some sample text`. But, as you may have noticed my above scenario is a bit more complex:

```
var s = "My temp folder is: [span]Path.GetTempPath()[/span]";

var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[span](.*?)\[/span]",
    m =>
        {
            var codeString = m.Groups[1].Value;

            // then you have to evaluate this string
            return EvaluateMyCode(codeString)
        });
```

Comment: How does that HTML relate to the given regex?

Comment: @revo Thank your for pointing out my typo. I just corrected it. It's `span` tag and not `test` tag in the given regex.

Comment: I think you would be better served dropping the regex and using HtmlAgilityPack instead.

Comment: XSL is designed to do things like this. This will be a bit of work whatever you choose because your output is structurally different from your input.

Comment: Allow me to post the obligatory link: [You can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5198140)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might need more steps, hence my variable naming, but one pattern repeated worked:

```
var p1 = new Regex(@"\s*<span>(?<text>.+?)</span>\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var s1 = src;
while (s1.IsMatch(p1))
    s1 = p1.Replace(s1, "${text}");
```

NOTE: If the pattern is exact, you could do it without looping by adding quantifiers around the beginning and ending `<span>`s:

```
var p1 = new Regex(@"(?:\s*<span>)+(?<text>.+?)(?:</span>\s*)+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var s1 = p1.Replace(src, "${text}");
```